# Deploying a Visual C# application with SQL server express database

Tags: c#

I have a visual c# 2010 application that connects to the SQL server 2008 express. 
How can I deploy my application including the database from sql server express without installing the SQl server 2008 express management studio?

Is it necessary to install sql server express in order to connect my application into the database?

Comment: To use a SQL Server database, you of course need to have SQL Server installed.

Comment: Instead of using SQL server you could try using a SQLite DB. Look here:
http://www.sqlite.org/ I think it will give you what you are looking for.